# Guava cache with async loading for non-blocking get

Tags: java, scala, caching, guava

I'm trying to use Guava cache with async loading of values and have non-blocking get(). Because I do load values from DB so it is pretty expensive, it would be OK to serve temporally out-dated data until new data is loaded in the background but not OK to block when trying to read from cache.

I first tried using `refreshAfterWrite` with `expireAfterWrite` but it does not seem to achieve what I'm looking to do. It seems from the documentation of [refreshAfterWrite](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh), entries needed refresh will not be remove until read which makes the call to `cache.get()` blocking!

> Automatically timed refreshing can be added to a cache using CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite(long, TimeUnit). In contrast to expireAfterWrite, refreshAfterWrite will make a key eligible for refresh after the specified duration, but a refresh will only be actually initiated when the entry is queried.

This is how i'm creating the cache, I define a loader like this:

```scala
class DbCacheLoader() extends CacheLoader[K, V] {
  override def load(key: K): V = {
    // read from DB
  }
}
```

Then, I tried using the `refreshOnWrite` option to build the cache like this

```scala
val syncLoader = new DbCacheLoader()
val val cacheLoader = CacheLoader.asyncReloading(syncLoader, threadPool)
val cache: LoadingCache[K, V] = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .refreshAfterWrite(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)  // timeout
  .expireAfterWrite(hardTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // hard timeout
  .concurrencyLevel(threadPoolSize * 10)
  .recordStats()
  .build[K, V](cacheLoader)
```

How can I have non-blocking `get()` with Guava cache?

Comment: I don't think your interpretation is correct. Let's say you set the refresh time to 1 minute and the expire time to 2 minutes. If you make a request after the 1 minute mark and before the 2 minute mark, you should get back the existing (stale) value immediately while it starts refreshing the value in the background (and stale values will be returned until either the refresh completes or the expire time occurs, whichever is first). However, if no requests are issued within 2 minutes of the last time the key was loaded...sure, you'll hit the expire time instead and be hit with a blocking call.

Comment: that's what I first thought when I implemented the cache but i when looking at the metrics (I tracked time to call `get()`) it seems it is not constant and follows the time to read from DB.

Comment: I also thought increasing the `expireAfterWrite` but I don;t think it would help as I found there are tons (> 100k range) of loads (I track the metric for the count of cache load) in contrast to evictions, so it is not like the cache is waiting for rows to expire to load them but probably it is doing the load when `get()` is called on keys needed refresh.

Comment: And looking at the code in [LocalCache.java#waitForLoadingValue()](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L2200) it does seem to be a blocking call!

Comment: Sure, but it depends on where `waitForLoadingValue` is getting called from. In `get`, it's only called if there's no value in the cache, and in `lockedGetOrLoad`, which is called from `get`, again if the value is null or expired.

Comment: oh right this is called when the value is already loading as it checks with `valueReference.isLoading()`

Comment: "How can I have non-blocking get() with Guava cache?" - Is that irrespective of refreshing, e.g. an `AsyncCache`? If so, then the `CacheBuilder` javadocs recommend using [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)

Comment: @BenManes yes i'm expecting refresh to not block get() as it is OK to serve stale data until background refresh finishes. I will check Caffeine wasn't aware of this library.

Comment: A confusion might be that refreshAfterWrite is triggered by activity. If you want a proactive refresh then you can use a scheduled task to periodically call `refresh(key)` and reload. That is sometimes desired when expiration shouldn't ever occur, which means it is a hot map rather than a cache, so a library is not actually needed vs plain Java.

Comment: @BenManes I am using an async reload (I wrap the loader with `CacheLoader.asyncReloading`), which should mean that when a key needs refresh, this would happen asynchronously and this is why I thought the get() should be non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing the [refresh](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#reload-K-V-) method on `CacheLoader`?

> This implementation synchronously delegates to load(K). It is recommended that it be overridden with an asynchronous implementation when using CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).

Seems like it might be required for the behavior you're seeking.

Comment: async refresh in `CacheLoader#reload` is already provided by this `val val cacheLoader = CacheLoader.asyncReloading(syncLoader, threadPool)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that. Neat!